# Perl, get all hash values

Tags: perl, list, hash

Let's say in Perl I have a list of hash references, and each is required to contain a certain field, let's say `foo`. I want to create a list that contains all the mappings of `foo`. If there is a hash that does not contain `foo` the process should fail.

```
@hash_list = (
 {foo=>1},
 {foo=>2}
);

my @list = ();
foreach my $item (@hash_list) {
   push(@list,$item->{foo});
}

#list should be (1,2);
```

Is there a more concise way of doing this in Perl?

Comment: I just wanted to clarify you're not creating a list of mappings, you're creating a list that consists of each hashes `foo` value., and your code example has nothing to do with 'process failing' so you're not just asking for more concise.

Comment: In general: whenever you find yourself doing `foreach ... { ... push.. }` you can make the code shorter and simpler using map or grep.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. there is.

```
my @list = map {
    exists $_->{foo} ? $_->{foo} : die 'hashed lacked foo'
  }
  @hash_list
;
```

Comment: for complex map expressions like this, it is usually easier to read using the block syntax rather than the bare expression

Comment: that's better +1, I use the bare syntax all the time for short expressions, probably the only long one that doesn't get a block is the case of a map that returns an arrayref: ` map [...] => ...`

Answer (score 2):

Evan's answer is close, but will return the hashrefs rather than the value of foo.

```
my @list = map $_->{foo} grep { exists $_->{foo} } @hash_list
```

Comment: Yea, I fixed this. and, I also made it die, there is a disconnect between his code and his question. You can also do this with one loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the map function for this :

```
@hash_list = (
 {foo=>1},
 {foo=>2}
);

@list = map($_->{foo}, @hash_list);
```

map applies the function in the first argument over all element of the second argument.

grep is also cool to filter elements in a list and works the same way.

Answer (score 1):

#### TLDR Answer

If you want to get the values of a hash, use the `values()` function.  Like this...

```
print Dumper(values %$hash);
```

#### Source

> **values HASH**
>
> In list context, returns a list consisting of all the values of the named hash.
>
> (Source: [PerlDoc.org.](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/values))

#### Demo

*Working Demo Online at:* [**IDEOne**](https://ideone.com/cZoVeh)

```
use Data::Dumper;

my $hash = {
    soybeans=>1,
    chickpeas=>2,
};

print Dumper(values %$hash);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( @hash_list != grep { exists $_->{foo} } @hash_list ) {
    # test failed
}
```